# after submitting form data, page not being properly loaded in laravel

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

i have a website in which there is a form, the form data after user submits is sent to my database and email.

below is my controller and route

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Register;
use App\Mail\SendEmail;
use Session;
use Mail;
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class RegController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        //
    }


    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

       // return $request;


// return $request->Fee;
            $data = new Register;
            $data->firstname = $request->firstname;
            $data->lastname = $request->lastname;
            $data->mobilenumber = $request->mobilenumber;
            $data->experience = $request->experience;
            $data->designation = $request->designation;
            $data->confirmation = $request->confirmation;
            $data->company = $request->company;
            $data->address = $request->address;
            $data->addressline2 = $request->addressline2;
            $data->city = $request->city;
            $data->state = $request->state;
            $data->pin = $request->pin;
            $data->country = $request->country;
            $data->Whatsapp = $request->Whatsapp;
            $data->alternatenumber = $request->alternatenumber;
            $data->Email = $request->Email;
            $data->CompanyRegNumber = $request->CompanyRegNumber;
            $data->Date_Incorporation_orBusi_Stp = $request->Date_Incorporation_orBusi_Stp;
            $data->GSTIN = $request->GSTIN;
            $data->Services_Offered = $request->Services_Offered;
            $data->Annual_Turnover = $request->Annual_Turnover;
            $data->Declaration = $request->Declaration;

            $data->termsandconditions = $request->termsandconditions;
            // $data->Fee = $request->Fee;
            $data->Mode_of_Payment = $request->Mode_of_Payment;

            $data->Recommended_by_A = $request->Recommended_by_A;
            $data->Recommended_by_B = $request->Recommended_by_B;

              $fee = $request->Fee[0];
              $data->Fee = $fee;

              if(!empty($request->Fee[1]))
              {
               $data->Fee1 = $request->Fee[1];
              }
              if(!empty($request->Fee[2]))
              {
               $data->Fee2 = $request->Fee[2];
              }
            if(!empty($request->Fee[3]))
              {
               $data->Fee3 = $request->Fee[3];
              }


 if($request->hasFile('Photo')) {
      $image = $request->file('Photo');
      $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
      $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Photo');

     Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
      $data->Photo=$filename;
    }
 if($request->hasFile('Receipt')) {
      $image = $request->file('Receipt');
      $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
      $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Receipt');
    Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
      $data->Receipt=$filename;
    }
 if($request->hasFile('Signature')) {
      $image = $request->file('Signature');
      $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
      $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Signature');
      Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
      $data->Signature=$filename;
    }

            $data->save();
            Session::flash('registered','reg');


        $name = $request->firstname." ".$request->lastname;
        $subject = "TEIA";
        $message =  $data->id;

         $photo = $data->Photo;
         $sign = $data->Signature;
         $recipt= $data->Receipt;
    $email = 'zubairking@gmail.com';


        // ->cc(['name1@domain.com','name2@domain.com'])
      Mail::to($email)->send( new SendEmail($subject,$message , $photo ,$sign,$recipt));




            return back();
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

```html
Route::get('/', function () {
 // Session::flush();
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::resource('register','RegController');
```

after the user submits the register button, the data is submitted and then the user is taken to the form with succes message on top. the problem is first time when the user submits the data, the the page gets stuck at https://booktheparty.in/TEIA/register with blank page. then when the user go back and submit again, then the page is directed to form page and shws succs message. but still the data is added 2 times to database. i want to know why my page gets stuck at the first time. can anyone tell me

Comment: Did you try use header() or redirect() to test if your code go back? Also is triggering some error? Your laravel.log show something?

Comment: did you try to change the `return back()`; to `return redirect('/register')` ?

Comment: @Jovs register is where my php code is there, my the page which i want to redirect to is "welcomeblade".. that is the home page, how will i do that

Comment: And about the second time "works" in fact the message you're seeing it's the session flash of the previous request. But as me and @Jovs tell you, did you try changing the ```return back();``` to ```return redirect("/register");```, for testing proposes you can use header("Location: register") too, but the session flash it'll not gonna work.

Comment: @FabioWilliamConceição am new to laravel, "register" is my controller, my form is in index blade. can you suggest as an answer of how to do it using the format you said

Comment: @subah please refer the documentation –> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects

I believe your answer you'll find here.

Comment: and also you can use in command prompt or terminal the `php artisan route:list` to check your route list and can use for your `return redirect();` and route for your forms.

Comment: @Jovs should i do it like return redirect()->route('welcome');

Comment: @FabioWilliamConceição should i do it like return redirect()->route('welcome');

Comment: noo noo if your welcome route is `/` then you should do it like this `return redirect('/');`

Comment: @jovs i did what you said but this is showing up "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier"

Comment: It's impossible, this is only happening if you try to redirect to a post/put route this message. Maybe it'll be better you show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace this code with your store function

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

       // return $request;


// return $request->Fee;
            $data = new Register;
            $data->firstname = $request->firstname;
            $data->lastname = $request->lastname;
            $data->mobilenumber = $request->mobilenumber;
            $data->experience = $request->experience;
            $data->designation = $request->designation;
            $data->confirmation = $request->confirmation;
            $data->company = $request->company;
            $data->address = $request->address;
            $data->addressline2 = $request->addressline2;
            $data->city = $request->city;
            $data->state = $request->state;
            $data->pin = $request->pin;
            $data->country = $request->country;
            $data->Whatsapp = $request->Whatsapp;
            $data->alternatenumber = $request->alternatenumber;
            $data->Email = $request->Email;
            $data->CompanyRegNumber = $request->CompanyRegNumber;
            $data->Date_Incorporation_orBusi_Stp = $request->Date_Incorporation_orBusi_Stp;
            $data->GSTIN = $request->GSTIN;
            $data->Services_Offered = $request->Services_Offered;
            $data->Annual_Turnover = $request->Annual_Turnover;
            $data->Declaration = $request->Declaration;

            $data->termsandconditions = $request->termsandconditions;
            // $data->Fee = $request->Fee;
            $data->Mode_of_Payment = $request->Mode_of_Payment;

            $data->Recommended_by_A = $request->Recommended_by_A;
            $data->Recommended_by_B = $request->Recommended_by_B;

              $fee = $request->Fee[0];
              $data->Fee = $fee;

              if(!empty($request->Fee[1]))
              {
               $data->Fee1 = $request->Fee[1];
              }
              if(!empty($request->Fee[2]))
              {
               $data->Fee2 = $request->Fee[2];
              }
            if(!empty($request->Fee[3]))
              {
               $data->Fee3 = $request->Fee[3];
              }


 if($request->hasFile('Photo')) {
      $image = $request->file('Photo');
      $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
      $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Photo');

     Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
      $data->Photo=$filename;
    }
 if($request->hasFile('Receipt')) {
      $image = $request->file('Receipt');
      $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
      $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Receipt');
    Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
      $data->Receipt=$filename;
    }
 if($request->hasFile('Signature')) {
      $image = $request->file('Signature');
      $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
      $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Signature');
      Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
      $data->Signature=$filename;
    }

            $data->save();
            Session::flash('registered','reg');


        $name = $request->firstname." ".$request->lastname;
        $subject = "TEIA";
        $message =  $data->id;

         $photo = $data->Photo;
         $sign = $data->Signature;
         $recipt= $data->Receipt;
    $email = 'zubairking@gmail.com';


        // ->cc(['name1@domain.com','name2@domain.com'])
      Mail::to($email)->send( new SendEmail($subject,$message , $photo ,$sign,$recipt));




            return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code:

```
return redirect('write the route you want to be redirected ');
```

after saving data in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

`return redirect()->back();` or `return redirect('')`